# Spark - change parallelism during execution

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hbase, distributed-computing

I have a job divided in two parts:

- The first part retrieves data from HBase using Spark
- The seoncd part computes heavy CPU intensive ML algorithms

The issue is that with high number of executors/cores, the HBase cluster is too aggresively queried and this may cause production unstability.
With too few executors/cores, the ML computations takes a long time to perform.

As the number of executors and cores is set at startup, I would to know if there is a way to decrease executor number for the first part of the job.

I would obviously like to avoid running two separate jobs like Hadoop would do with mandary disk serialization between these two steps.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess [dynamic allocation](http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/dynamic-allocation-in-spark) is what you are looking for. This something you can use with spark streaming as well.

I think you may have to play a little with your RDD size as well to balance data ingestion and data processing but depending on what's your real use case it can be really challenging.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What do you mean with 'play a little with your RDD size'. Is it dividing data retrieving into 10 RDDs and then make an union of them ?

Comment: I ment that the way you repartition your RDD at each stage and most specifically the earliest one for your case if my understanding is correct (you want to reduce your number of partition and slow your application down at purpose ) . In the phases you  need more executors and you would like to have more executors repartition with  more partitions and the dynamic allocation may do the rest. 
 Use your explain() to ensure it always behave like you want at each steps .